# Thermodynamic statements

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

Question 13 from [1, p. 4.2]:

> Which of the following statements is true?
>
> (a) An ideal gas always obeys the equation: $PV^γ = \mathrm{constant}$ in adiabatic process.
>
> (b) An ideal gas always obeys the equation: $PV^x = \mathrm{constant}$ in
>   polytropic process.
>
> (c) In a polytropic process, the heat capacity of the system remains same
>   throughout.
>
> (d) In all the cyclic process, $w_\mathrm{net}$ by the system is non-zero.

To me (a), (b) and (c) appear to be correct, but the solution manual says only the (c) is right.

#### References

1. Neeraj, K. *Advanced Problem in Physical Chemistry for Competitive Examinations*, 2nd ed.; Pearson India Education Services Pvt. Ltd: Dehli, Chennai, **2015**. ISBN 978-93-325-4373-7.

Comment: Please avoid posting textual information as a screenshot. Also, it would be nice if you cite the source of the question (e.g. a textbook reference), otherwise it may be considered a plagiarism. As for the question, neither (a) or (b) mention that the process is reversible.

Comment: Yes I will make sure of it from the next time. It was my first post. And yes I totally forgot  about the reversible part. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for adding the reference, I corrected the styling and publisher's info.

Comment: Understood the format now . Will take care of it from the next posts . Thank you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) is not true, because, in addition to being adiabatic, the process must be reversible.

(b) is not true, because the gas must be assumed to have constant heat capacity for this equation to apply